# Which compiler for default templates args in function

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-construction

Is there a compiler which would complile function template definition with new C++ feature namely default templates arguments in function definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html), GCC supports default template arguments for function templates since version 4.3.

Note: to enable C++0x support in GCC, add `-std=c++0x`  to your `g++` command line.